# Azure Net backend Publishing, must I really delete Migration before adding another?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure-mobile-services

I have an MVC .NET backend for an Azure Mobile App, where I'm employing Entity Framework V6 Code First Migrations, however, when Publishing it does not mark the Migrations as having been deployed but it does deploy them to the Azure SQL Database. So, if I make a change to my model, I have to manually delete the migration in the Migration folder and then Add-Migration again, or I get a Pending Migration error (below). Rinse and repeat for every change. Shouldn't the Publish Web program mark these migrations as having been performed?

I've followed the tutorial here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/

In my Startup.MobileApp.cs File, I initially use the below code to get everything synced up, and it works;

```
// Use Entity Framework Code First to create database tables based on your DbContext
Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());

public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

This works too; Enabling-Migrations, Adding a Migration, changing the Startup.MobileApp.cs File to point to the Configuration file, checking the Execute Code-First Migrations in the Publish Web program, and then Publishing:

```
// Using Code First Migration, so no need for Initializer unless reseeding or resetting database.
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Migrations.Configuration());
migrator.Update();

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyService.Models.MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()

    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());
    }
}
```

However, if I make a change to my model, and then try to add another migration to the migration folder I get this error:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201608181434049_Name]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

But if I manually delete the Migration, then I can add a new migration, and the publisher runs and backend database is updated correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't check the box for applying migrations.

In your `App_Start\Startup.MobileApp.cs`, remove the DbInitializer() call and replace it with:

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Migrations.Configuration());
migrator.Update();
```

For my article on the subject, see: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/

Comment: Excellent answer Adrian! Thank you, I'm now migrating successfully. In your article you point out that this is a particularly difficult area for developers to get working correctly, and I would echo that. There are a lot of caveats to take into consideration. For example, because I had a local database that was not in sync with my Azure database, I needed to delete the local mdf file and migrations folder and Azure database, then run enable-migrations -force. Once I did that I was able to Add an Initial migration, Publish, and then run Update-Database. Now it all works!

Comment: I have followed your guides for Code First Migration in .net backend, every time faced problems. This time after following your book and after hours of debugging find out that I have to create the local db first which by default doesn't do that by applying (update-database). Before (update-database) you have to apply:
(sqllocaldb.exe stop)
(sqllocaldb.exe delete)
Then
(update-database).
Why nobody stating that?
Thank you for your tutorials.

Comment: @Adrian Hall I have everything set up correctly and my Migrations have been working fine, up until I manually dropped a table from my SQLPro for MSSQL Explorer and then went back to my Azure backend code and deleted it from there to match the two. After this, it doesn't matter how many changes I make in my backend code. No migrations take place, even though my code now matches what's in the database. How do I fix that?